# onNewIntent not called or order is wrong in my app

Tags: android

I have a onNewIntent() problem on my project, and looking for some help.

Background:
I am working on a "screenlock"-like application, in my app; There are **two** processes, a service in ProcessA, which will create an activity when the screen is off (receive SCREEN_OFF intent). And the created activity will be in processB.

I want to do some work in my onNewIntent(), but I find it shows after onResume in some special operation. I will explation with the log.

```
 10-30 13:50:13.334 3619-3619/com.luisclient:lock D/luisDebug: invoke1 
 10-30 13:50:14.415 3564-3564/com.luisclient D/luisDebug: onCreate 5837
 10-30 13:50:14.465 3564-3564/com.luisclient D/luisDebug: onResume 5837
 10-30 13:50:14.485 3564-3564/com.luisclient D/luisDebug: onPause 5837
```

Above is the first time the activity be created, as the screen is off now, onPause is called after onResume() immediately.

```
 10-30 13:50:16.828 3564-3564/com.luisclient D/luisDebug: onResume 5837
 10-30 13:50:18.779 3564-3564/com.luisclient D/luisDebug: onPause 5837
```

Above is the screen on logs.

```
 10-30 13:50:28.099 3619-3619/com.luisclient:lock D/luisDebug: invoke1 
 10-30 13:50:28.159 3564-3564/com.luisclient D/luisDebug: onResume 5837
 10-30 13:50:28.169 3564-3564/com.luisclient D/luisDebug: onPause 5837
 10-30 13:50:28.169 3564-3564/com.luisclient D/luisDebug: on new intent
```

***Above*** is my problem, when the screen is on, I leave the activity without finishing it. After a while, I press the power key, and **onNewIntent() called after onResume()** as the log shows

```
 10-30 13:50:33.174 3564-3564/com.luisclient D/luisDebug: onResume 5837
 10-30 13:50:34.565 3564-3564/com.luisclient D/luisDebug: onPause 5837
 10-30 13:50:34.635 3619-3619/com.luisclient:lock D/luisDebug: invoke1 
 10-30 13:50:34.645 3564-3564/com.luisclient D/luisDebug: on new intent
 10-30 13:50:34.685 3564-3564/com.luisclient D/luisDebug: onResume 5837
 10-30 13:50:34.695 3564-3564/com.luisclient D/luisDebug: onPause 5837
```

**But** what weird is: If I press power off with the activity on the screen, **onNewIntent called before onResume**.

Can anyone explain why this happens? It will be very helpfull.

Here is the code of AndroidManifest.xml and start function.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.LockActivity"
        android:label="@string/empty"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:taskAffinity="com.luisclient.lock"
        android:theme="@style/LockScreenTheme" />
     <service
        android:name=".service.LocService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:process=":lock" />

    public static void invoke(Context context, boolean firstComeIn) {
       Log.d("invoke2 " );
       Intent intent = new Intent(context, LockActivity.class);
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```